# Forced shut down results in not being able to boot 50+ times

Tags: boot, shutdown

When I shut down my PC normally using the OS (Win7), the system will boot fine next time I turn it back on.

However when I shut it down forcefully, either during boot or normal OS operations, it will not boot up at all the next time. Black screen, no USB power to devices.

With forceful shut down I mean holding down the power button for 10 seconds. But also unplugging will at 100% of tries result in the boot problem, while normal shutdown will result at 100% in an ok boot.

The only thing which helps is turning if off and on again about 50-100 times, at some point it will come back to life.

Boot fail = there's no video signal. HDD motors start, but even with all HDDs or any (good) combination of the RAM modules removed, nothing.. I even tried an old video card, there should at least be some boot up messages coming up. The ticking noise during failed boots adds to the mystery. It's not coming from the hard discs (removed them).

The mainboard battery is new - when it comes back the BIOS settings are not reset.

What possible reason could there be for that kind of behavior?

Comment: Some other observations: There is a slight periodic (ca. 2 per second) ticking noise coming from the mainboard (ASUS) when the boot fails. The ticking goes away when I hold down down the MemOK button (and comes back when I release it). The MemOK LED stays on during failed boots. But memory must be ok or it would never boot.

Comment: Ticking usually is the hard drive: the only moving parts are going to be HD platters/heads, the fan, and any optical drive. I would get a backup drive or networked drive and start a mass-backup once you get booted up as soon as is practicable. You may have a bad sector or sectors in the hiberfile area of the drive, so a normal boot might not hit that.

Comment: could You provide some more information? During the black screen, what is going on? Is there a processor/HDD/CD ROM activity?

Comment: With forceful shut down I mean holding down the power button for 10 seconds. But also unplugging will at 100% of tries result in the boot problem, while normal shutdown will result at 100% in an ok boot. No random factors there interestingly. boot fail = there's no video signal. HDD motors start, but even with all HDDs or any (good) combination of the RAM modules removed, nothing.. even tried an old video card, there should at least be some boot up messages coming up. The ticking noise during failed boots adds to the mystery. It's not coming from the hard discs (removed them).

Comment: Sounds most like a motherboard issue, some like a PSU problem, which is often easier and cheaper to test.   I assume that the ticking is that very subtel ticking comming from the power curcuit stuff, not the hard disk?  There can be "clamping" occuring when things like magnetic coils have the power passed through them  and fans that are not starting up correct. also mosfets (rare) against heatsinks,  can give off some sound. If the ticking was the issue (and it might have something to do with it), you could use sound isolation A tube/hose to your ear aimed to find the location of the noise.

Comment: Your "forced shutdowns" aren't good for the filesystems on your HD, but it should at least boot up and do something, you'd see the POST &/or splash screen, be able to access BIOS, etc. Unplugging the HD, or anything else plugged in, should rule out problem devices; If it boots to POST/BIOS then whatever you unplugged last was the problem. I used to have some USB devices that would cause similar "freezes" for a few seconds to minutes, but It sounds like you already tested unplugging everything.

Comment: It was in fact the power supply ticking. Swapped it and now everything's ok. Still left wondering a bit why forced vs. normal shutdown mattered to the PSU. Thanks @all here.